# Where does Tomcat7w.exe store Settings on Windows

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I had endless problems finding an answer to this question when trying to make a backup of my existing settings before making wild modifications that I wanted to test.

I finally have an answer that I'd like to share with the denizens of stack overflow in case anybody else is having the same problem!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value is stored in the windows registry in a really unintuitive place.

```
HKLM > Software > Wow6432Node > Apache Software Foundation > Procrun 2.0 > [Your Instance Name]
```

Comment: The path in 32-bit OS: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\tomcat7`

Comment: Some additional documentation about service manager used: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html