# how to start tomcat debug port in windows while debugging tomcat application

Tags: java, tomcat, remote-debugging

I'm getting Exception while debugging

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect.
```

i have tried command in windows system

> netstat -n -a -p tcp

but my port 8787 was not there how to start that port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic config is:
In `catalina.bat` under `tomcat/bin` file modify the below.

1. `CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"`
2. `JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"`
3. Run Tomcat from command prompt: `catalina.sh jpda start`

Then in eclipse create a debug configuration:

- Write any name for the configuration.
- Write the project name.
- Write the connection type as Standard(Socket Attach)
- Host should be localhost
- Port as 8000( or any port number, but that should be the same in other places also).

see: [Remote debugging Tomcat with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835612/remote-debugging-tomcat-with-eclipse)

Comment: by default eclipse is taking 1043 as a port now.
how i don't know??
when i am trying to do with eclipse UI but now it is taking default port where it is defined?

Comment: No one else has given a hint so I'll give a shot by searching for JPDA_OPTS in all .bat files inside bin but it should be in catalina.bat or setenv.bat

Comment: dt_socket port is by default at startup 1043 how please help me.
while manually starting tomcat 7.

Comment: If you start it manually specify the port like this, in windows: `bin\startup.bat -debug 8000`

Comment: then i get socket error but after configuring in eclipse port number 1043.
when manually starting it takes 1043 as port number.

Comment: well that might be because the port is being used by another process, so try another port or kill that process

Comment: after using telnet i am not able see that port also

Comment: Thanks,I have changes in catalina.bat also seen many options such as `-Xmx,-XX:PermSize` etc thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

When run as windows service, Tomcat's command line options could be stored in registry at `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\TomcatServiceName` path for 64-bit OS and at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\tomcat8` for 32-bit.

See [Where does Tomcat7w.exe store Settings on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027879/where-does-tomcat7w-exe-store-settings-on-windows).

Those settings can be viewed and changed via running `bin\tomcatw.exe`.